# Checking specific users' access rights in different groups

Tags: lua, boolean-logic

In Garry's Mod I'm trying to make it so only certain user groups could use context menu. But it only works either for vip or superadmin user groups. Not for both. Could anyone tell me what might be wrong?

```
hook.Add("ContextMenuOpen", "SuperAdminContext", function()

if not LocalPlayer():IsSuperAdmin() or LocalPlayer():IsUserGroup("vip") then return false end end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is combining wrong. The code hides the menu if the user is **not** a superadmin — so far so good — **or** if the user *is* a vip — which is quite wrong on both counts. Instead, one of two approaches: either make sure that 1) for all possible groups to show, the user is **not** in them (using `and` to ensure all conditions apply), or 2) none of the possible groups to show applies (using `or` and parentheses to group). Examples of each:

1. ```
   if not LocalPlayer():IsSuperAdmin() and not LocalPlayer():IsUserGroup("vip") then
   ```
2. ```
   if not (LocalPlayer():IsSuperAdmin() or LocalPlayer():IsUserGroup("vip")) then
   ```

Negation with Boolean logic is notoriously tricky, but it almost always boils down to a question of carefully considering the details.

Truth tables can help. Here's the truth table for our desired composite condition:

```
IsSuperAdmin()  IsUserGroup("vip")  Result (hide menu)
False           False               True
True            False               False
False           True                False
True            True                False
```

This looks exactly like the standard truth table for `or`, except that the last column is precisely inverted. That's a good sign that approach 2 is a good match.

Comment: Thank you very much! very detailed explanation. Makes perfect sense now. And works like a charm.